# Does python could receive hive console output?

Tags: python, hive, pyhive

Because I using python to control hive data etl flow, and I use pyhive to connect hive and execute HQL.
I want get more information from hive, like tez session execution output or hive's java error exception output.
How should I hack pyhive package, that I could get this kind results?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.
You could use the exception message.

```
# Using Try Exception 
try:
    # What you want to execute
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

Then you would get the console output results for error exception.